# Codeigniter isn't working when migrated to production server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

my codeigniter project is not working after migrating to production. I assume this is die to path issues.

This is how development server looks like (all CI files are placed in root folder) my project worked good.

```
www/
   application/
   system/
```

Production server looks like

```
www/
   app/
       application/
       system
```

How can i make it work with including app folder
ex; www.myhostname.com/app/controller/method/4

Comment: First, try in your /app/application/config/config.php change `$config['base_url'] = "http:// www.myhostname.com/app/"`. If it does not work then try out in the production server change .htaccess file and replace RewriteBase / by RewriteBase /app/ or show us .htaccess file in your /app folder if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

also you have to specify the application file path `$application_folder = 'app/application';` in `index.php` ( hope you found your main index.php file )